# Ensuring fields are filled before submission

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am creating a webform for a user to fill out. I would like the all fields to be filled before the user can press the submit button. The submit button is disabled until the required fields are filled. However the button does not become active even with the fields set.

[![view of the page][1]][1]

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" id="testForm" ngNativeValidate>

 <p-dropdown [options]="supervisor2" [(ngModel)]="selectedSupervisor2"placeholder="Select a Supervisor*" optionLabel="name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required ></p-dropdown>

 <p-dropdown  [options]="leaveCodes2" placeholder="Leave Code*" optionLabel="name" required></p-dropdown>



  <p-calendar  [showIcon]="true" [minDate]="minDate" [readonlyInput]="true" placeholder="From Date*"
              id="setter" required >
            </p-calendar>

 <button pButton type="submit" label="Submit" [disabled]="!testForm" (click)="submit()" class="ui-button-success"
            id="righter"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: man! if you are using jquery inside of angular application, you are doing it wrong!! take a look at reactive forms in angular to validate your form array

Comment: Absolutely agree with Reza. DONT use jquery in angular if there isn't some REALLY REALLY good reason to do it. Angular has its own tools to do things like this. Here jQuery is totally unnecessary. Please read about forms: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: @Reza Thanks, I did take a look and boy thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Im still having an issue and I have updated my original post

Comment: @AJT_82 thanks for that link. Ive read up and I have edited my question. I would appreciate it if you took a look for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you dig deep into reactive forms, they are great. Might be confusing at first, but totally worth it. But you have started a template driven form. I suggest you read more about them in the documentation, since you have some crucial things missing.

First, don't mark the form with `id`, it should be a template reference: `#testForm="ngForm"`. Then you are missing `name` attributes from the form controls, the `name` attribute together with ngModel registers the form controls to the form. How you incorporate ngModel can vary with two ways. Either you have a variable using ngModel, like you have on one field using two-way binding, for example: `[(ngModel)]="selectedSupervisor2"`. If you do not a have a variable binding on a field, you need to mark just `ngModel` on the field, so that the form control will be registered.

If you then want to disable button when form is not valid, you should use `[disabled]="!testForm.valid"`. So from all these comments, your (shortened) code should look like:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(testForm.value)" #testForm="ngForm">
  <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="selectedSupervisor2" name="supervisor" required></p-dropdown>
  <p-dropdown name="leaveCode" ngModel required></p-dropdown>
  <p-calendar name="fromDate" ngModel required></p-calendar>
  <button pButton [disabled]="!testForm.valid"></button>
</form>
```

When you pass the form value to submit, you get the values neatly in that object. Also no need to add click event to button, since buttons inside forms are by default of type `submit` and form will be submitted when button is clicked, even without the click function.

Comment: Thank you so much. i read up on template based forms and it helped me tremendously. I will try making a reactive form next!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it helped! Yes, reactive forms have great stuff and inbuilt functions. Especially if you are looking into arrays, reactive forms have `FormArray`. Arrays are not so easy to deal with in template driven forms. So it's totally worth it to learn about reactive forms :) Good luck and happy coding!